# GeoEvent streaming service labeling in ArcGIS Online or Portal

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-portal, geoevent-processor

Is it possible to label streaming services within AGOL or Portal?  There is not a `create label` option available after adding a streaming service to AGOL or portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 10.3.1 it is not possible as per [this documentation](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/create-labels.htm):

> You can create labels for features in hosted feature layers, ArcGIS Server feature service layers, individual layers from ArcGIS Server map service layers, CSV on the web, and layers from files.

Strangely there is a streamLayer label class in the JS API but it's not available in AGOL.

Confirmed this with tech support which sparked the debate "was this oversight or purposely designed this way"

Comment: Thanks for sharing the outcome.  I imagine if the capability is there, it will make it into a subsequent release of AGO.  Pending which template your using, might not be too much work to host your template externally and modify to include labelling.  Im doing the same right now with the map journal but tweaking some styling.